# How to get values of ContextHubInfo & NanoAppInstanceInfo using ContextHubService "CHRE"?

Tags: java, android

example:

```
ContextHubService hubService = new ContextHubService(this.getContext());
int[] noOfContextHubs = hubService.getContextHubHandles();
            for(int i :noOfContextHubs){
                ContextHubInfo hubInfo = hubService.getContextHubInfo(i);
                Log.e("ContextHubInfo: Name", hubInfo.getName());
                Log.e("ContextHubInfo: Vendor", hubInfo.getVendor());
                Log.e("ContextHubInfo: Toolchain", hubInfo.getToolchain());
                Log.e("ContextHubInfo: ID", ""+hubInfo.getId());
           }
```

Similarly i need to get multiple data's of **NanoAppInstanceInfo** like below???

I nanohub : osLog: [NanoMinion] received MSG Type 0x21, Version 0, 182 bytes

I nanohub : osLog: [CellLocator] cell position success (2828m)

I nanohub : osLog: [WifiLocator] wifi position success (49m)

I nanohub : osLog: [LocEng] Sending Scan Request with interval ~60 seconds, ~960 meters

I nanohub : osLog: [GeofencingEngine] LocationCallback: provider 1, accuracy 59 meters, 1 transitions